# Dado um número X, verificar se em uma lista existem 2 elementos que somados resultem em X

Tags: python

Problema: O usuário digita um número X, e uma função deve verificar se dois números somados dentro de uma lista, contento elementos que podem ser ' ' ou números inteiros, resulta no número X do usuário.

Minha função:

```
# Tentei fazer 2 laços fors, para percorrer a soma da lst[0] com os outros, da lst[1] com os outros, etc.

def plus_element(num, lst):
i1 = 0
i2 = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        if isinstance(lst[i1], int) and isinstance(lst[i2], int):
            if lst[i1] + lst[i2] == num:
                print(f'{lst[i1]} + {lst[i2]} é igual ao número {num}.')
                return
        i1 += 1
    if isinstance(lst[i1], int) and isinstance(lst[i2], int):
        if lst[i1] + lst[i2] == num:
            print(f'{lst[i1]} + {lst[i2]} é igual ao número {num}.')
            return
    i2 += 1
```

O erro que estou tendo é que se a lista tem mais de 2 números, a função dá erro.

```
# Minha lista
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 
' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 
' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' 
', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' 
', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 5, 2, 10]
```

O erro que apresenta:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Alguém saberia me ajudar?
Desde já agradeço a atenção.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não precisa percorrer a lista inteira duas vezes.

Basta percorrer do índice atual até o final. Por exemplo, eu começo do primeiro elemento e testo a soma dele com todos os outros (do segundo em diante).

Depois eu começo do segundo elemento e testo a soma deste com os outros, mas do terceiro em diante. Não preciso testar de novo a soma do segundo com o primeiro, pois isso já foi testado anteriormente.

E vou assim até o penúltimo, testando a soma deste com o último. Assim:

```
lista = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 
' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 
' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',
5, 2, 10]

def plus_element(num, lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1): # vou do primeiro ao penúltimo
        for j in range(i, len(lst)): # vou do atual até o último
            n1, n2 = lst[i], lst[j]
            if isinstance(n1, int) and isinstance(n2, int):
                if n1 + n2 == num:
                    print(f'{n1} + {n2} é igual ao número {num}.')
                    return True
    return False

print(plus_element(15, lista)) # True
print(plus_element(1000, lista)) # False
```

Também fiz a função retornar `True` ou `False`, indicando se foi encontrado ou não. Mas eu prefiro que a função não imprima nada e só retorne o resultado, e quem a chamou que faça o que quiser com o resultado (imprima a mensagem, etc):

```
def plus_element(num, lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        for j in range(i, len(lst)):
            n1, n2 = lst[i], lst[j]
            if isinstance(n1, int) and isinstance(n2, int):
                if n1 + n2 == num:
                    return (n1, n2) # retorna uma tupla com os números
    return None # não encontrou

num = 15
result = plus_element(num, lista)
if result is not None:
    n1, n2 = result
    print(f'{n1} + {n2} é igual ao número {num}.')
else:
    print(f'Não foi possível encontrar 2 números que somam {num}')
```

---

Se não for um exercício, tem um jeito mais simples, usando o [módulo `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from itertools import combinations

def plus_element(num, lst):
    for n1, n2 in combinations(lst, 2):
        if isinstance(n1, int) and isinstance(n2, int):
            if n1 + n2 == num:
                return (n1, n2) # retorna uma tupla com os números
    return None # não encontrou
```

`combinations` já retorna todas as combinações dos elementos da lista.

---

E se tem vários elementos que não são números, talvez seja melhor filtrar somente os elementos que você quer, e só depois testar as combinações entre eles:

```
def plus_element(num, lst):
    for n1, n2 in combinations(filter(lambda e: isinstance(e, int), lst), 2):
        if n1 + n2 == num:
            return (n1, n2) # retorna uma tupla com os números
    return None # não encontrou
```

No caso, usei [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) para pegar somente os elementos que são números, assim a quantidade de combinações já diminui bastante no seu caso.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui entender essa lógica, é muito mais simples do que eu pensava.

Answer (score 5):

O colega @hkotsubo já explicou o problema e mostrou soluções, e eu aproveito para mostrar outra forma de resolver o problema que também é bem eficiente, uma vez que apenas percorre a lista uma só vez:

```
def plus_element(num, lst):
    encontrados = set()
    for elem in lst:
        if isinstance(elem, int) and (num - elem) in encontrados:
            return num - elem, elem
        encontrados.add(elem)
    return None
```

[Veja o código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ajlVay)

Esta solução usa um `set` adicional para ir marcando os elementos já encontrados, pelo que sempre que encontra um novo elemento pode saber de imediato se o par do novo elemento já saiu, e caso tenha saído tem uma solução válida.

Exemplo: Você quer a soma para 7. Passa pelo 2 e regista esse numero, de seguida quando passa no 5 que você sabe que o par é 2 pois 7 - 5 dá 2. Como esse número já saiu tem um par válido, o numero atual e o par dele.

No código o `encontrados = set()` é o `set` que regista os números que já saíram e o `(num - elem) in encontrados` é o que verifica se o par do numero atual já saiu.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @PedroBarretto Estamos cá para isso mesmo!